# In Xcode 4 version control, what does it mean when there is a question mark near a file that you have just added to the project?

Tags: xcode, version-control, xcode4.2

How do you change it to ensure that the file is properly added?

I copied some files into my project folder. Then in Xcode I clicked on a group and chose "Add files to project...". Then I selected multiple files.

One of the files was added properly - It had an "A" next to it. The other file had a "?" mark next to it.

Why didn't it add properly? What should I do to add it properly? It is a PNG file.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The ? mark means that the file is not under source control (but is part of the project). You can add it to the project by clicking on the file ---> Source Control ----> Add.